Error When Using get_datasets with the OECD Package in R
I’m trying to download data from the OECD database using the OECD package in R, but I’m encountering an error when I call the get_datasets() function.
Here’s what I’ve done so far:
I installed the OECD package using the following command:
install.packages("OECD")

After installation, I loaded the package:
library(OECD)

When I attempt to retrieve the datasets with:
datasets <- OECD::get_datasets()

I receive the following error message:
Error in read_xml.response(httr::GET(url, ...)) : Not Found (HTTP 404)

R version: R version 4.4.1 (2024-06-14 ucrt)
Additional Information:
I checked if the OECD API is currently accessible by visiting their website.
I’ve also tried updating the OECD package, but the issue persists.
Does anyone know how to resolve this error or if there are any known issues with the OECD API?
Thank you!

It seems errors have already been reported to the package maintainer. You can see open issues at https://github.com/expersso/OECD/issues. It's unclear if the package is being maintained any more. What version of the package are you running?

I understand, thanks for the link. it looks like there are many unresolved issues with the package. It seems that it may no longer be actively maintained. I'm currently using the latest available version. Do you know of any previous versions that are still available and functioning properly?

Maybe try the browser based search OECD Data Explorer, since without updates the old package wont work anymore.
